# Make async task run synchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I noticed a lot of similar questions like mine, but I didn't found a solution working that fit my needs.

I have a `Test` method which declare at first an `Action` to be executed and then call an async method called `ExecuteActivityAsyn`c to runt that action.
The action consist on some async methods called one after another like that:

```cs
public async Task Test()
{
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;

    Action taction = new Action(async () =>
    {
        this.Insert();
        await this.Method1();
        await this.Method2();
        await this.Method3();
        await this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    });

    await this.ExecuteActivityAsync(taction);
}
```

The `ExecuteActivityAsync` method is as below:

```cs
private async Task ExecuteActivityAsync(Action act)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StartExecution");

        await Task.Run(act).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");

        });

        Console.WriteLine("EndExecution");

        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

I trying to assure that the `Action` created is being executed from the beginning to the end before the "Completed" message pops out on the console, but actually I have that it came out as soon as `async Method1` is called.

I expect the messages in the console in that order:

```
"StartExecution"
-Method1 executed
-Method2 executed
-Method3 executed
-SaveChangesAsync executed
"Completed"
"EndExecution"
```

but the actual result is:

```
"StartExecution"
-Method1 executed
"Completed"
-Method2 executed
-Method3 executed
-SaveChangesAsync executed
"EndExecution"
```

For sure there is something I'm missing out, but I tried with all suggestions like:

```cs
Task.RunSynchronously()
Task.Wait()
Task.Result
```

with no luck.

Someone has some hints how to solve it or can point to me some links to check a solution?

Comment: Adding the await with the Async method effectively runs the code Synchronously since the code is blocked until the Async completes.

Comment: Then why does the ContinueWith statement runs even if the related task (which execute the action) didn't yet concluded ??

Comment: @jdweng No, that's false.  If `await` was just like `Wait` then `await` wouldn't have been added as a keyword in the first place, as `Task.Wait` was in the previous version of .NET and the language.  awaiting something doesn't synchronously wait, it adds a continuation.

Comment: You are creating an `Action` (a delegate which takes nothing and returns nothing) from an asynchronous method which takes nothing and returns `Task`. This throws away the task, which is what you await. You need to keep the `Task`. To do this, you have to make your delegate a `Func<Task>` rather than `Action`. There is no need for `Task.Run` or `ContinueWith` - just `await act () ;`

Comment: @AntonTykhyy *"This throws away the task"* -- Most likely a `Task` is never created, so there is nothing to throw away. The `async` delegate inside the `new Action` is [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), i.e. it returns [`void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void).

Comment: @Servy : await block until async is completed which is what sync does.  Wait is a time object and simply times out.  await need a complete response before continuing.

Comment: @jdweng No, it doesn't block.  It adds a continuation to the task which will continue running the async method.  That's radically different, in that it is specifically asynchronous and not synchronous.  You can feel free to read the [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) if you'd like to learn more about what the keyword does.

Comment: @Servy : You link title is "await operator - asynchronously await for a task to complete" which is exactly what Sync does.  Async may use interrupts while sync may not.  But both wait until complete when await is used.

Comment: @jdweng Great, you succeeded in clicking the link, which told you that `await` is asynchronous, rather than synchronous.  I don't know why you think reading the word "asynchronously" in the title made you think it was synchronous, rather than asynchronous, but if you're still confused, try reading beyond the title and read the rest of the article where it will explain in more detail what that entails.

Comment: @Servy : using Async with await is equivalent to Sync since both with wait until the method completes before continuing.

Comment: @jdweng: I believe you're thinking of "serial" (one at a time), not "synchronous" (blocking).

Comment: @StephenCleary : Sync is always one at a time since you cannot run a method a second time without completing the first time. Async you can run more than once because because you can return from method and call a second time without finishing the first time.  Async means not synchronous.  I'm qualified to teach a communication course and know what sync and async really means.  Don't argue this with me.

Comment: @jdweng You are not qualified to teach a communication course. You have been [spreading completely false information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392514/11683) for years on this site, this question not being an exception. If you hadn't started doing that way before the AI hype, I would have flagged you as an AI bot.